# How to count total of result aggregate mongodb returns?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

My query use aggregate to summary all alert group by alert type, filter by houseId.
I can count only total alert of a group.
How I can count total alert of a house ( total of all group )

```
db.getCollection('alerts').aggregate([{
  $match: {
    houseId: ObjectId("609100a56ed9f8001351aee3")
  }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$type',
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        alerts: {
            $push: {
                _id: '$_id',
                type: '$type'
            }
        }
     }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[{
    "_id" : "cool",
    "count" : 1.0,
    "alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "cool"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "_id" : "hot",
    "count" : 2.0,
    "alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "hot"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "hot"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I expect a field total: 2  = cool alert + hot alert

Comment: Use another group stage and sum the count values.

Comment: Is it unable to count in only 1 query ?

Comment: Can you give me a example ? @prasad_

Comment: Maybe something like this StackOverflow post: [Count nested and outer data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68455232/count-nested-and-outer-data/68456012#68456012)

Comment: @parsad: Sorry I wrong about my expected, actually, I want a total = number of group. Not total alert, current I have to create 1 query to count by add section $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: 1 }} to get only total groups. Can I query in only 1 query ?

Comment: You can include the expected result document in your question post.

Comment: I edited my question, expect total = 2

Comment: Is it sufficient to get the length of the array?

Comment: @Joe length of array is fine if I get all the data, but if I request with pagination, it's wrong because total return to UI can know how much the data